# /usr/share/code/bin/../code: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file:

Tags: linux, debian-based

/usr/share/code/bin/../code: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

getting this error when install visual studio code in debian amd64

Comment: There is a similar question on AskUbuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123722/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-cannot-open-shared-objec)

Answer (score 1):

I add the same error trying using codium inside docker container. The solution given by Steve Mak (https://medium.com/@ssmak/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-c1918b75acc3) work fine.

You need to install missing packages this list : *gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget*